# Find all the Kirchhoff's circuit equations in a multiple batteries circuit

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, kirchhoffs-laws

So I saw this exercise where it says to find all the currents that flow in the circuit and all the equations for the currents and voltages. Any help would be more than welcome[image: ![Circuit]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQfIU.png)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Unfortunately, EE.SEE is not a homework help center. If you show your effort and progress first then I'm sure you'll get help here.

Comment: You need to show at what point you are stuck.

Comment: Kirchoff's laws make possible to write an equation for every node (=the sum of the currents towards a node=0) and an equation for every loop where the sum of voltage drops along the loop is zero. Solving the currents and voltages do not need all of them, It's enough to have a minimum set where all parts are presented.  I guess you should by yourself work through some examples from a textbook or lecture notes. You shouldn't outsource the most elementary skills.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl9ivQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I used Mathematica to solve this circuit. The code I used is the following:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I6 + I5, I6 + I2 + I9 == 0, I8 == I2 + I1, 
   I9 == I3 + I4, I3 + I8 + I7 == 0, I4 == I7 + I5, 
   I1 == (V5 - V6)/R1, I2 == (V4 - V6)/R2, I3 == (V4 - V6)/R3, 
   I4 == V4/R4, I5 == -V8/R5, V5 - V8 == V1, V5 - V4 == V2, 
   V6 == V3}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, I8, I9, V4, V5, V6, V8}]]
```

Using your values, I ran the following code:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I6 + I5, I6 + I2 + I9 == 0, I8 == I2 + I1, 
   I9 == I3 + I4, I3 + I8 + I7 == 0, I4 == I7 + I5, I1 == (V5 - V6)/5,
    I2 == (V4 - V6)/7, I3 == (V4 - V6)/4, I4 == V4/2, I5 == -V8/10, 
   V5 - V8 == 2, V5 - V4 == 4, V6 == 6}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, 
   I8, I9, V4, V5, V6, V8}]]
```

And it gave me the following result:

```
{{I1 -> 24/835, I2 -> -(92/167), I3 -> -(161/167), I4 -> 179/167, 
  I5 -> -(346/835), I6 -> 74/167, I7 -> 1241/835, I8 -> -(436/835), 
  I9 -> 18/167, V4 -> 358/167, V5 -> 1026/167, V6 -> 6, 
  V8 -> 692/167}}
```

Which can be approximated as follows:

```
{{I1 -> 0.0287425, I2 -> -0.550898, I3 -> -0.964072, I4 -> 1.07186, 
  I5 -> -0.414371, I6 -> 0.443114, I7 -> 1.48623, I8 -> -0.522156, 
  I9 -> 0.107784, V4 -> 2.14371, V5 -> 6.14371, V6 -> 6., 
  V8 -> 4.14371}}
```

Comment: I down-voted because providing answers to no-effort-shown homework questions is "feeding the trolls" and encourages users to post such questions here without actually learning anything.